# Loopback Swagger HTML doesn't show Parameters for the Endpoints

Tags: node.js, swagger, loopbackjs, swagger-ui

In a NodeJS based project, the Swagger that comes with loopback-component-explorer (version 2.7.0) doesn't show the "Parameters" in the HTML page in which we can provide the required params for the Rest endpoints, regardless the http verb (e.g. GET, POST, PATCH etc). Must the remoteMethod(...) definition follow some Swagger requirements?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out.

When defining the Loopback remoteMethod(...), the option "http.source" for "accepts" should be set to anything different than "req", "res" and context (e.g "body", "form", "query" and "path").

Comment: Yes, that is covered here: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-methods.html#argument-descriptions